# Unable to have function properly populate array from text file, seems to skip first line/be one off

Tags: c++, arrays, text

So I have two simple questions. One is my function okay for reading a text file composed of one number on each line and passing it an array inside main()? And is the text file opening/closing properly or do I not understand the code?

And secondly, I can't seem to fill my array correctly. There's 92 numbers/lines, but I can only seem to get 91 elements. It seems to skip the first number, but I'm not sure why. When I'm debugging I can see "number" reading the the first line, but I don't know where it goes.

The text file is 92 numbers with decimals, with a number in each line like this..and the first number is in the first line, no space above and no vertical space between the numbers.

31.11

25.22
...

```
int getTempData(double temperatures[]) {

    ifstream input("pgm6.txt");

    if (!input) 
        return 1; // closes input file

    string number;

    while (input >> number)

        for (int i = 0; i < 91; i++)

        {
            input >> temperatures[i];
        }
}
```

and inside main()

```
const int ARRAY_SIZE = 91;
double temperatures[ARRAY_SIZE];
getTempData(temperatures);
```

Edit: Thanks so much for the help everyone. I learned my lesson in not using code I don't quite understand from here: https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/2wwv6i/c_creating_writing_to_and_displaying_text_files/

```
#include <fstream> // Instead of <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std; // Nothing too much wrong with this...
int main() {

    ifstream input("input.txt"); // Open the file "input.txt" for reading 
    (if = input file)

    if ( !input ) // Did the file open correctly?
    return 1;

    ifstream output("output.txt"); // Open the file "output.txt" for writing 
    (of = output file)

    if ( !output ) // Did the file open correctly?
    return 1; // C++ automatically closes the input file!

    string word;

    **while ( input >> word )** // Read a word while the file isn't at its 
      end

    output << word << '\n'; // Write the word on its own line

    // C++ automatically closes the output file
   // C++ automatically closes the input file
}
```

Comment: What's the point of `while (input >> number)`? Why do you have both a `while` loop and a `for` loop? It's hard to understand why your code does what it does because there are no comments.

Comment: "So I have two simple questions" - then you should ask *two* individual questions.

Comment: Why are you using C-style arrays where you have to worry about passing their size instead of using `std::array`s or `std::vector`s that know their `.size()`?

Comment: You pass an array that holds 91 elements, thus 92 is technically out of the question :-). Your for-loop collects 91 elements! But you waste first line on the while-loop. If your input has 92 numbers, then the while loop is gone thru only once.

Comment: Your `getTempData` function can fall out the end without returning a value. That's Undefined Behaviour. Don't do that.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I did sense there were better ways to do it, but it's for an assignment so I assume there's some benefit in learning it the harder way

Comment: @Moose Only if you want to stay in the past and write C++ like we did in the bad old days, 20 years ago. My guess is; your teacher is just not up-to-date with modern C++ (17, or 14 if you must).

Comment: @JesperJuhl Ah that's really unfortunate! My teacher seems competent, but I guess he has to follow the book/curriculum. And also, thanks for the advice about the function, we were told to use to make it void, but I thought using if (!input) was better than what we were taught. I still have a lot to learn obviously.

Comment: @BoR Hahaha techinically out of the question was great. I'm getting the 0-91 confused, so thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @Moose If you declare a function to return a type ( `int` in this case), then it *must* return that type on *all* paths.

Comment: @Jesper Juhl That makes sense, I assumed it just had to return something. Didn't realize there were differnet paths. Thanks, I'm learning a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve seems to boil down to this:

```
#include <fstream>

int getTempData(double temperatures[]) {
    std::ifstream input("pgm6.txt");

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 92 && input >> temperatures[i]; i++) {
        // deliberate empty line
    }
    // input will close file on exiting function
    return i; // returns number of elements found
}


int main() {
    const int ARRAY_SIZE = 92;
    double temperatures[ARRAY_SIZE];
    getTempData(temperatures);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while (input >> number)
```

This reads the first number and throws it away. Simply remove this line of code.

Also, you should probably add error checking to `input >> temperatures[i];`. And your function needs to return something if all is well -- currently there is no `return` statement at the end. Also, your loop only collects 91 elements.

Comment: Ohh okay, that makes sense. Thanks so much. I got it from here https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/2wwv6i/c_creating_writing_to_and_displaying_text_files/ and I clearly don't understand it well. Also, it seems to work by returning 1, but I don't know.

Comment: @Moose Piece of advice: Do not ever use code you don't understand unless you are very, very experienced. That is a very difficult thing to do and if you're thinking it's some kind of shortcut to having to figure things out for yourself, you're *very* wrong. If you want to use code someone else wrote and you are not an experienced coder, you *must* thoroughly understand what it does and how it does it.

Comment: Throughly understand is the key word. I thought I understood what that code was doing, but I was completely off. And now I undertand your previous comment about returning something if everything is well.